# Mobile field on Task object

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, formula, salesforce-id

I want to configure task object under Activity. I need to add a field mobile in to task object. I need to show the field on the task page and on the reminder window. For this I try to create a new field on task object but not able to find the any option to create a custom field on task. Please help me to resolve this issue. My salesforce account is a group Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For custom task and event fields, click Your Name | Setup | Customize | Activities | Activity Custom Fields.

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/adding_fields.htm

There are certain limitations though, for eg you can't create Lookup fields, but you should be alright for Mobile.

It is however not currently possible to customise the activity reminder popup, so you wouldn't be able to add Mobile on there. (Some people append it to Subject if they need to see it on the reminder.)
http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HB98AAG

[image: Here's a screen shot of adding a custom Activity field on Activity Page Layouts]

Comment: thanks is was great help for me. But in my sales force account (it is a group edition) I am not able to find Activity Custom Fields under Activity. Is their any limitations.

Comment: Unfortunately it would seem like its not yet possible for Group Edition http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KbJtAAK

Answer (score 2):

Even though you can have custom fields .still you cannot have on pagelayouts .

Please see the idea

http://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrLzAAK

Its running under ideas .Please do vote for this.

Comment: It's an Edition thing. Possible on EE, but not lower Editions. On GE you can't add Activity Custom Fields

Comment: @techtrekker Agree with that.But you cannot add custom field into page layouts too and that is one of the requirement as well.

Comment: Again , like I said, on UE and EE orgs you can add custom task fields to page layouts. http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000HYWjEAO